# jenkins push submodule with main repo

Tags: git, jenkins, gulp, jenkins-plugins

I have a JavaScript Repo on github which uses gulp to create build. Gulp creates a folder name **dist** in main project.

```
gulp build
```

What i want to achieve is that, i should push this **dist** folder to some other git repo so any one can take only build using git and need not worry about development code.

I have takes approach of git submodules here https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules. Following this article i am able to achieve manually.

For automation of this,i have created

- Jekins job which clones this main repo and created a build on Jenkins using gulp. Than i am running below code in Execute shell

  cd dist

  git submodule init

  git submodule update

  git fetch

  git merge origin/master

  git checkout master

  cd ../

  gulp      //this updates the dist folder with new files if any

  cd dist

  git add -A

  git commit -am "added test files"

  git push //not working

There is option of git publisher but don't see any option for submodules push there. I also need to update my main repo which keeps the track of submodule version

Any advice or article ref will help ? is there any other way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer

Took the other approach to do this. Instead of one job created 2 jobs

1. first one does the job of pulling main project and create a build. Once build is created, it been archived using Copy Artifact Plugin.
2. Other job takes pull of other dist repo from git and copies build archived artifacts and if any changes pushed to that respective git repo.

[This article](http://www.russellallen.info.gridhosted.co.uk/post/2011/06/04/Creating-a-Simple-Build-Pipeline-with-JenkinsHudson-and-NAnt.aspx) helped, this was simple.